# What is the difference between "-c opt" and "--copt=-O3" in Bazel build (or GCC)

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization, bazel

I'm learning GCC and Bazel. I want to enable all the optimization for Bazel to build a project which requires the best performance.

Then I found `-c opt` which means to set the compilation mode to optimized without debug information.

And -`-copt=-O3` means set the optimization level to the third one. There are `-O2`, `-Os`, etc.

I'm confused with these two options.

1. What is the difference between `-c opt` and `--copt=-O3`?
2. Will they trigger each other. So I only need to write one of them with `bazel build`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`--copt` is for passing args to to the compiler.

`-c` is a short form of [--compilation-mode](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--compilation_mode).
Its effect is described in the [user-manual](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#semantics-options):

- It sets compiler options (e.g. `-c opt` implies `-O2 -DNDEBUG`)
- There are different output directories per compilation mode, so you can switch between debug and optimized builds without full recompilation.

So usually, `-c opt`is enough. If you want the behaviour of `-c opt` but with a different optimization level, you combine the two options like in `-c opt --copt=-O3` and the compiler will get both options `-O2` and `-O3`, but the last one will win.

And watch out, there is a third similar option:

`--config=configname` is for selecting a configuration. You can have a `.bazelrc` which defines default options. Some of them are not always active, but some only if you activate them by the `--config=configname` command line option. Now `opt` is a popular configname, so if you have a `.bazelrc` that contains

```
build:opt --copt=-O3
```

then `bazel build --config=opt` has the same effect as `bazel build --copt=-O3`

Comment: Thank you very much! I also found someone mentioned "--config=opt". Now everything is clear.